# What program can I use to get copier/fax functionality from separate scanner and printer?

Tags: software-rec, printing, scanner

It is difficult to find a good multifunction laser printer in my price range.  But there are several good cheap laser printers (non-multifunction) and I have an excellent scanner (better than I could get on a multifunction).

But making copies would be a pain if I had to operate the printer and scanner separately.

Is there a program or script that can imitate the copier &/or fax functions of a good multifunction printer by automating the scan and passing it to the printer?

Answer (score 3):

xsane has the posibility to select what should be done with the image after it is scanned.

[image: xsane action select]

Here you can select

1. Viewer - The normal view before save
2. Save - Just save it to a specific filename (and inc a number so you can repeat it multiple times)
3. Copy - Send to a printer
4. Multipage - ???
5. Fax - Send to a fax
6. E-main - mail it.

So I guess that copy and fax it what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a relativly easy job to write a script for. There are lots of scan programs (xsane) that can be scripted. Setup some default values, have it scan to a temporary pdf file then send the file to the printer.

Conceptually it's easy. You will have to play with your particular setup each step of the way, but it shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 0):

check [scanadf](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_scanadf.htm)

Comment: In here, we prefer more than just links to pages. A little bit of a summary/explanation will help.